# Documentation to jQuery Formwizard (site not available anymore)

Tags: jquery, formwizard

I'm using an old HTML template to build a system which uses [jQuery Codemine Formwizard](https://github.com/thecodemine/formwizard) forms, but since [thecodemine](http://thecodemine.org/) website doesn't exist anymore and I do need to read its documentation, does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: does this question belong to stackoverflow?

Comment: Where else does it belong? I really would like to know

Comment: may be you should ask them via their github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for options, methods and events has been added to the README.md file on github. All the examples are available on the formwizard github repo as well.